# Has the Rasberry Pi website taken on a new theme?

Tags: official-foundation

I was just popping over to the Raspberry Pi blog/official site to check out the news about a ported GPU driver (which can be [read here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/6561)) and I noticed that the site looks ... different.

Take a look at the screenshot:

[image: screenie of RPi Blog]

Is this just me, or did they change the design for something and I missed it?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Looks like a Warez site

Comment: These unicoins are awesome!

Comment: @ppumkin I totally agree! :D Unicoins FTW!! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/6586) by Liz talking about the new design, and

> [...]which we plan on using to repel new customers from now on.

It's supposedly also designed for good reading on an RPi. I think, we can safely assume this madness will be over by tomorrow.
(The question that stays is wheter the Quake III bounty is an April's Fools as well, or not...)

Comment: Midday which time zone? Ahh, but if they really weren't a bunch of "twits" they would see where you come from based on IP and dynamically turn of the prank at your current midday time. They are our friends though and allot of users go there form here or come here from there. But i prefer Unicoins instead of 80's black/red ascci art, too.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe that's because today is April 1?

[April Fools' Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day)

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking...like SE's version too :D